# Discord Chat bot keeps hitting 1000 connection limit;

Tags: heroku, token, discord, chat, minecraft

I have a Discord Bot that was made up so that I could connect the chat channel from a game to my discord server's chat, that way players could talk back and forth without having to necessarily be in-game. However, the Bot keeps connecting to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period, and as such, Discord automatically resets the Bot's token.

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this so that the Bot can be constantly running?

This is the code for the Bot: https://github.com/sstuebs/PhilthyPhil
I am also keeping this Bot running 24/7 via Heroku, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The Procfile in your project is missing info. Here's a detailed [guide](https://anidiots.guide/other-guides/heroku#setting-up-the-project)